# Automatically change text in div from a list

Tags: jquery, html, text, automation, cycle

I'm building a site at the moment with an introductory section that states "I am a [role]".  What I want to do is declare a list of roles (i.e, web designer, UX developer, graphic designer etc) and have the text in [role] to cycle through each one automatically.

Something similar to:

HTML:

```
<p>Hi there I'm a <span id="role"></div>.</p>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#role').html('web designer').delay(400).html('graphic designer')
    .delay(400).html('UX developer');
});
```

I know this is a solution for it but how can I achieve this by declaring a list of "roles" first of all and then have the html cycle through the list?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try a simple solution using [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) and array operations

```
jQuery(function($){
    var roles = ['role 1', 'role 2', 'role 3'];
    //used to determine which is the next roles to be displayed
    var counter = 0;
    var $role = $('#role')
    //repeat the passed function at the specified interval - it is in milliseconds
    setInterval(function(){
        //display the role and increment the counter to point to next role
        $role.text(roles[counter++]);
        //if it is the last role in the array point back to the first item
        if(counter >= roles.length){
            counter = 0;
        }
    }, 400)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XK6M8/)

Comment: thanks that's just what I needed.  Do you know how I would implement a fadeIn, fadeOut effect each time it changes 'role'?

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/kLvp3/) for the solution.

```
$(document).onReady( function () { 
    var roles = [ 'web designer', 'graphic designer', 'UX developer' ];
    var roleId = 0;

    window.setInterval(function () {
        $('#role').html(roles[roleId]);
        roleId = roleId + 1;
        if(roleId >= roles.length) { roleId = 0; }
    }, 1000);
});
```

I used setInterval() to make the list continously repeat, but that is of course optional. You can define the roles as an array and iterate through them on a timer. If you want to loop through only once you can for a for loop instead.